# how can i trigger click function as auto (every 15 second)

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example if i have a random div..

```
$("#random").click(function{
 $("#random").toggle("slow");
});
```

How can i trigger to click function as auto(every 15 seconds).

Thanks for helps..

Answer (score 4):

Look up window.setTimeout.  Then in the callback function for that, set the setTimeout again and call the click.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#random").click(function{  
    $("#random").toggle("slow"); 
}); 


function funcName() {
    $("#random").click();
}

setInterval(funcName, 15000);
```

Think this should work ( not tested )

Comment: don´t use setInterval, use setTimeout, he just want to run it once, and you cant use () in that method, because if you do it will run direct and not on the interval/timeout: `setTimeout(funcName, 15000);`

Comment: @voigtan he mentioned every 15 seconds.